Want to know the Exchange version of outlook account in Office.js (Outlook web addin)
I am trying to get Exchange version of my outlook account, like; Outlook 2016, 2019 or O365.
in Outlook web addin, I tried following line of code but I could not get result:
Office.context.mailbox.diagnostics.hostVersion)]

is there any way to get Exchange name or version?

Can you go into more detail on what you are getting? The docs say "If the mail add-in is running in Outlook on a desktop or mobile client, the hostVersion property returns the version of the Outlook client. In Outlook on the web, the property returns the version of the Exchange Server." From my experience this works well.
